# StartCoroutine only works for more than 1 object if it starts when the game launch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to apply the same Coroutine for 5 objects, when the coroutine starts at the lauch of the game the 5 objects do that Coroutine but when I make them start trough other class only 1 object start the coroutine.

This is the code that make the 5 objects start the coroutine:

```
public class NpcMoveRandomly : MonoBehaviour
{
    NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
    public float timeForNewPath;
    public bool inCoroutine;
    Vector3 target;

    void Start()
    {
        navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!inCoroutine)
        {
            StartCoroutine(MoveRandomly());
        }
    }

    Vector3 getNewRandomPosition()
    {
        float x = Random.Range(-5, 5);
        float z = Random.Range(-5, 5);

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, 0 ,z);
        return pos;
    }

    public IEnumerator MoveRandomly()
    {       
        inCoroutine = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeForNewPath);
        GetNewPath();
        inCoroutine = false;

    }

    void GetNewPath()
    {
        target = getNewRandomPosition();
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(target);
    }
}
```

Now the code that only 1 object start the coroutine (I'll show just the differences):

```
//public bool inCoroutine; I changed the inCourotine to startCoroutine but the rest of the code is basicly the same
public bool startCoroutine;

void Update()
{
    if (startCoroutine)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveRandomly());
    }
}

public IEnumerator MoveRandomly()
{
    startCoroutine = false;
    ...
    ...
    startCoroutine = true;

}
```

In other class:

```
public NpcMoveRandomly npcMoveRandomly;

public void Method()
{
    npcMoveRandomly.startCoroutine = true;
}
```

So when I make the coroutine start with the lauch of the game, because the inCoroutine its false for default, its all ok but when I make the startCoroutine true trough other class the coroutine only applies to 1 object. I really don't know why and how to manage this.

Comment: so do you have the comp `NpcMoveRandomly` on 5 gameobjects in the scene? And from which class is the second code sample

Comment: Yes I have on the 5 gameobjects, and the second code sample is from other class that is doing other things before I want to make the 5 gameobjects move randomly, basicly I can call the  startCoroutine there it will be the same, but I prefer to put the bool true.

Comment: It's seems like you are passing the reference to only one object in your other class, if you what to all your 5 objects start the coroutine, you must pass each objecto to the other class and set their boolean to true.
You can also pass an array of game objects and set all boolean to true.

Comment: But who is receiving the gameobject is the first script, in the second script I'm only making the startCoroutine to true, thats why im so confused.

Comment: Its like @ClovisIgnacioFerreira is saying. You are referencing one object, so only one will get triggered. You have to reference all of them and then start all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a gameobject named NPCManager in your scene and reference there all your npcs. If they exist already in the scene at the beginning, just drag and drop them in the editor into your public array:

```
class NPCManager{
     public NpcMoveRandomly[] npcList;

     public void Method(){
          foreach(NpcMoveRandomly npc in npcList){
              npc.startCoroutine = true;
          }
     }
}
```

Or modify NPCManager to a singleton and add the npc directly after instatiating them to this array/list.....what ever, there are a lot of ways to do that.